# What's the case for semaphore passing a value greater than zero

Tags: ios, semaphore

Most of the articles I've found are using semaphore for usage of waiting a task finished, then do the rest of tasks. In this case, semaphore is always start with a value 0, and then increase the value in the completeHandler.

However, according to documentation:

> Passing a value greater than zero is useful for managing a finite pool of resources, where the pool size is equal to the value

I've tried to find an example for this case, but which turn out all I've found are talking about using `dispatch_group_wait` for waiting for multiple tasks finished. Would someone please give me an example and scenario for the case using a semaphore with a init value greater than `0`?